# OR in S3 Policy Condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk

This is my S3 policy

```
  {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policybla",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "StmtGoo",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::coes/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::coes"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-bla"
            }
        }
      }
   ]
```

For now I only allow access for 1 VPC, but now I want to add access to another one, so I was wondering how can I do an OR in the condition.

```
   "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
                "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-bla"
            },
        "StringEquals": {
                "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-foo"
            }
       }
```

This could works?

Regards.

**SOLUTION**

I just need to add a new Statement in the array with the same config but the VPC id

Comment: Can you give details what this policy is going to allow? Because S3 access to VPC I am seeing for first time?

Comment: I think does not matter here. But if you ask, we allow everything in the bucket

Comment: I found the solution, I just need to add a new Statement in the array